# Formatting pdf in Java

Tags: java, itext

I have some problem with formatting pdf. I already add text to pdf file but there is problem- I don't know how pdf will look like. I mean there is much more than one template and on one pdf I add in good place, however on another my text cover some important informations.

```
/**
* metoda dodaje podpis do pdf
* @param fileDokument
* @throws DocumentException
* @throws IOException
* @throws SQLException 
*/
private void addSignatureToPdf(FileDokument fileDokument) throws DocumentException, IOException, SQLException {
   java.util.Date dateToFind = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   int year = dt.getYear();
   int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
   int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();

   File f = new File(fileDokument.getFileNazwa());

   String operator = produkt.getOperatorProwadzacyForRolaAndDate(dateToFind, 5).toString();
   operator = operator.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "").trim();

   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(""+fileDokument.getFileNazwaFile());
   int height = (int) reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight();
   int width = (int) reader.getPageSize(1).getWidth();
   int fontSize = getFontSizeAdjustingToScreenSize(height);
   int marginCompatibility = getMarginCompatibilityAdjustingToScreenSize(width);
   int heightBelow = getHeightBelowAdjustingToScreenSize(width);

   File outFile = File.createTempFile("pismo_", ".pdf", MainApp.tmpDir);

   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
   BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ITALIC, codingType, false);
   PdfContentByte over;

   int total = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
   for (int a = 1; a < total; a++) {
       stamper.setRotateContents(false);
       over = stamper.getOverContent(a);
       over.beginText();
       over.setFontAndSize(bf,fontSize);
       over.setTextMatrix(marginCompatibility, heightBelow);
       over.showText("Za zgodność z oryginałem Radca Prawny " + operator + ", Wrocław, dnia " + df.format(day) + "-" + df.format(month) + "-" + year + "r.  .................. (podpis)");  
       over.endText();
   }
   stamper.close();
   MainApp.openFile(outFile);

}
```

My idea is to scale pdf to make it a bit smaller and add TextField which will always be empty and won't cover any text. Can you help or give other ideas, please?

Comment: If you want to try without scaling to find free space on a page, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503289/1729265) might interest you.

Comment: I'm only interested to add text on the bottom of the page. I could modify this code to only try to find empty fields under the text but it seems to be more complicated that my first idea. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case please have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419296/1729265). It is for iTextSharp and C# but should be easy to translate. If you need help translating, please say so.

Comment: Yeah, that's something what I'm looking for. I think I can translate it by my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really thanks to @mkl and @Bruno Lowagie!

Final answer:

```
/**
 * method to shrink pdf file
 * @param writer
 * @param stamper
 * @param reader
 * @param page
 * @param factor
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void shrink(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper, int page, float factor) throws IOException
{
    com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle crop = stamper.getReader().getCropBox(page);
    float diffX = crop.getRight() * (1 - factor);
    float diffY = crop.getTop() * (1 - factor);
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary pageN = stamper.getReader().getPageN(page);
    stamper.markUsed(pageN);
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray ar = null;
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject content = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.getPdfObject(pageN.get(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS), pageN);
    if(content == null)
        return;
    if(content.isArray())
    {
        ar = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray((com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray)content);
        pageN.put(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS, ar);
    }
    else if(content.isStream())
    {
        ar = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray();
        ar.add(pageN.get(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS));
        pageN.put(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS, ar);
    }
    else
        return;
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer out_p = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer();
    out_p.append(factor).append(" 0 0 ").append(factor).append(' ').append(diffX).append(" ").append(diffY).append(" cm ");
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStream stream = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStream(out_p.toByteArray());
    ar.addFirst(stamper.getWriter().addToBody(stream).getIndirectReference());
    out_p.reset();
}

/*
* method adding box with "Za zgodnosc..." on the bottom of the page
*/
private void addBoxToPage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader reader, int page, float factor, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper, String operator) throws com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    int year = dt.getYear();
    int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
    int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();
    com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle box = reader.getCropBox(page);
    box.setTop(box.getTop() - factor * box.getHeight());
    com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(page);
    cb.setColorFill(BaseColor.YELLOW);
    cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);
    cb.rectangle(box.getLeft(), box.getBottom(), box.getWidth(), box.getHeight());
    cb.fillStroke();
    cb.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
    ct.addElement(new Paragraph("Za zgodność z oryginałem Radca Prawny " + operator + ", Wrocław, dnia " + df.format(day) + "-" + df.format(month) + "-" + year + "r.  .................. (podpis)"));
    ct.setSimpleColumn(box);
    ct.go();
}
```

and that's how I call it

```
   int total = reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1;
   for (int a = 1; a < total; a++) {
       shrink(stamper, a, factor);
       addBoxToPage(reader, a, factor, stamper, operator);
   }
```

Comment: You actually do not need to provide an additional parameter `PdfWriter writer`, just like in the C#/iTextSharp method in [the source answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419296/1729265) you can retrieve the `writer` from the `stamper` using `stamper.getWriter()`.

Comment: The same for reader? I mean instead of additional parameter reader I can use stamper.getReader()?

Comment: You made at least 2 mistakes which I corrected: you used `CONTENT` instead of `CONTENTS` and you forgot to add a space character between `diffX` and `diffY`. The `cm` operator requires 6 operands and when you forget a space between `diffX` and `diffY`, you only have 5 operands. That's invalid PDF syntax. Also: what are you going to do if `crop` is zero? What are you going to do if the page contains annotations? Have you thought about that?

Comment: Yes, you can, also just like in the source answer.

Comment: @Bruno *what are you going to do if crop is zero* - afaik `getCropBox` by default gets the Media Box which should exist. But you are right, I'm not sure whether those methods look for inherited values also...

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, I don't really change that .pdf file. I just modify it by writing into temporary file and let the people to print it. I don't change the orginal .pdf I just manipulate it and don't save.

Comment: If the end purpose is to print the document, then you don't need to worry about annotations. Someone should double-check if `getCropBox` defaults to returning the `MediaBox` value if no `CropBox` is defined (I don't know this by heart).

Comment: @Bruno `getCropBox` contains `if (cropBox == null)
            return getPageSize(page);` but neither `getCropBox` nor `getPageSize` considers inherited values.

Comment: OK, now that we know that this code works, we can up-vote it ;-)

Comment: By the way, the hint from the original c# answer applies here, too: *Hint: `shrink` has to be used before retrieving the `OverContent` or `UnderContent` of the page.*

Comment: @mkl What do you mean? I actually has one really rare problem- if content of pdf is not stream and look like this: content: [358 0 R, 359 0 R, 360 0 R, 361 0 R, 362 0 R, 363 0 R, 364 0 R, 366 0 R] then the site with that content is blank.

Comment: Your `if(content.isArray()) {...}` code block still is erroneous.

Comment: @Michu93 you'll immediately spot the difference when you compare your code and the c# code front the original message.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I made mistake, I'm going to fix it on monday and then edit this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @mkl I edited answer and works like a charm. Thanks guys!