# Setting new page size to existing PDF document using Java IText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I want to set a new page size to my existing PDF document without cropping the contents. I am writing the following code but it just crops my PDF file from the bottom resulting in the loss of content.

The current size is 8.26" X 11.69 " and I need to make it 8.5" X 11".

My code only converts 11.59 to 11. Tried to change 8.26 but its not woking.

Can any one please help? I am using itextpdf-5.5.8 with Java.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.GrayColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfRectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class PageSize {

    public static final String SRC = "C:/Temp/BC.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "C:/Temp/BC_New.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PageSize().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        // properties
        PdfContentByte over;
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(55, 76, 560, 816);
        PdfArray mediabox;
        float llx, lly, ury,llz;
        // loop over every page
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
            mediabox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
            llx = mediabox.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
            lly = mediabox.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
            llz = mediabox.getAsNumber(2).floatValue();
            ury = mediabox.getAsNumber(3).floatValue();
            mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber((lly + 50)));
            over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
            over.saveState();
                       over.restoreState();
        }



        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
Here is the code I used to reduce 11.69" to 11". It works fine. But, it won't increase the width 8.26 to 8.5"

```
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.GrayColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfRectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class PageSize {

    public static final String SRC = "C:/Temp/Test.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "C:/Temp/BC_New.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PageSize().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        // properties
        PdfContentByte over;
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        PdfArray mediabox;
        float llx, lly, ury,llz;
        // loop over every page
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
            mediabox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
            llx = mediabox.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
            lly = mediabox.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
            ury = mediabox.getAsNumber(3).floatValue();
            mediabox.set(0, new PdfNumber((llx - 17)));
            mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber((lly + 50)));
            over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
            over.saveState();
                       over.restoreState();
        }



        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**SOLVED:**

It was a problem with the source file which I was trying to modify. The original source file was a 8.26" X 11.69". A hava program adds a logo to the file and saves it into a new file.

Somehow due to this conversion, the new source file's X-axis got locked and hence my program was not able to modify the x axis.

Hence, I move my program as the first step and it worked. My program first modifies the x and y axis and then passes the file to the other program which does the logo adding stuff.

Thanks Bruno on this. :)

Comment: You say "I am using iText-2.1.4 with Java." Your code says "import com.itextpdf.text." This is a contradiction. Your code is iText 5 code. You can't use it with iText 2.1.4. You shouldn't even be using iText 2.1.4. For more info, read the answer to [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially)

Comment: Oh. My Bad, I had both libraries placed and got confused which one I was using. Updated my question. Its itextpdf-5.5.8. Thanks for the response. Any suggestion or improvements to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the page size without changing the content.

If you want to shrink the content, then you need code that is more complex. See [Shrinking the contents of a pdf page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406925/shrinking-the-contents-of-a-pdf-page) for an example. There's also an example in the official documentation: [How to shrink pages in an existing PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-shrink-pages-existing-pdf)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary page;
PdfArray crop;
PdfArray media;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(p);
    media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
    if (media == null) {
        media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
    }
    crop = new PdfArray();
    crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
    crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
    crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() / 2));
    crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(3).floatValue() / 2));
    page.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, crop);
    page.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, crop);
    stamper.getUnderContent(p).setLiteral("\nq 0.5 0 0 0.5 0 0 cm\nq\n");
    stamper.getOverContent(p).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
}
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

If you want to enlarge the content, then you can simply change the UserUnit. Changing the UserUnit is also explained in the official documentation: [How to rotate and scale pages in an existing PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-and-scale-pages-existing-pdf)

```
float factor = 2.5f;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfDictionary page;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(p);
    if (page.getAsNumber(PdfName.USERUNIT) == null)
        page.put(PdfName.USERUNIT, new PdfNumber(factor));
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

This code will scale up the page and its content with a factor 2.5 (because that's what we defined as `factor`).

**UPDATE**

In your update, you have this:

```
    mediabox = pageDict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
    llx = mediabox.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
    lly = mediabox.getAsNumber(1).floatValue();
    ury = mediabox.getAsNumber(3).floatValue();
    mediabox.set(0, new PdfNumber((llx - 17)));
    mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber((lly + 50)));
```

By doing so, you add 0.236111 inches in `x` direction (`llx -17`) and you subtract 0.69445 inches in `y` direction. If you say that this changes 11.69 to 11 inch, then I assume that you're talking about the Y direction. If the original width in X direction was originally 8.26, it should be about 8.50.

I don't understand your problem. Of course: my calculations assume that there's no CropBox in your document. Is there a CropBox present?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it, but it is just shrinking my page size by the factor. Is there any direct way to first set the page size to Letter i.e. 8.5" X 11" and then go ahead and add the contents? My current page size is A4 i.e. 8.26" X 11.69".

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or you don't understand PDF. The content in a PDF page is fixed. Every character has a fixed position on the page. You can't change the page size and hope the content will reflow. PDF isn't made for that. You are confusing PDF with a Word processing format.

Comment: My understanding here was, I will take a PDF with A4 size, read its content, create a new PDF file with Letter size, add the contents to it and the content should fit in. I guess my assumption was not close enough. What I am trying to achieve is, I will get a PDF file which is of A4 size and I wanted to make it of Letter size with the same contents and similar layout. With the approach I have mentioned in the original post, I am able to shrink 11.69 to 11" but not the 8.26 ". I thought if by manually doing this(https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1269098?tstart=0) its doable, why not through code.

Comment: Why don't you combine my code to shrink the content with your code to change the page size?

Comment: Unfortunately, my code is only converting 11.69 to 11" but NOT 8.26 to 8.5". If you can help me out with this one, I can go ahead and combine your code with mine to make it work.

Comment: I don't have the time to chat.

Comment: Sorry for that. Chat invitation appreared by mistake. I have updated the original post with the code I used to modify the height from 11.69 to 11". Thanks for your help on this so far.

Comment: I don't understand the question. See my update: I've done the Math, and it should work. Unless there's a CropBox in your document. Is there?

Comment: Even I did the right calculation. But it just doesn't change the 8.26". It remains same whatever values I pass to mediabox.set(0, new PdfNumber((llx - 17))); The code I provided is complete. Its just a small program. And no, there isn't any crop box in my code. Not sure if its due to some hidden margins or something. Is it because of over.saveState();
over.restoreState();?

Comment: Its done. :) Updated my answer. Though I am not sure how did it blocked the X-axis.